# How to make a link / button redirect to a different address based on which user clicks it

Tags: javascript, html

To make it simple, i have a menu that contains the items "W", "X", "Y" and "Z". Each item redirects to a different page on the website, regardless of the user. But i want item "Z" specifically to redirect to a different page depending on the user. For example, if user "1" clicks on "Z", then he will be redirected to the page `example.com/z1`. If it is user "2" who clicks on "Z", then he will be redirected to `example.com/z2`. And so forth.

Something like:

- `if user = user1, then button_Z = <p><a href="http://reddit.com/">Z</a></p>`
- `if user = user2, then button_Z = <p><a href="http://youtube.com/">Z</a></p>`

User1 is redirected to reddit, while user2 is redirected to YouTube.

Comment: How are you identifying the user in your code?

Comment: Ah yes, i should have specified it. It will be based on their role. For example, 3 users will have the role "TeamA", 2 users the role "TeamB" and so on.

Comment: Are you authenticating your users, are the pages created via a back-end language, such as PHP, Node, Deno or anything else? Because if you're creating these links in the front end, there's a strong likelihood that your users may notice the scripting that modifies the URL.

Comment: What did you tried? we don't implement your requirement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas yes the backend side has already been taken care of by my friend. The users have unique names and their own passwords to login. I edited my post for better clarification.

Comment: It still needs clarification about how users might be identified in your code.  Is there a cookie that contains the information about the user?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes there is a cookie system. Users log in, the same way i logged in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting to do some pretty simple string concatenation in the url. Here's a simple example that show what it sounds like you're trying to achieve. Most likely you're going to want to get these variables out of the global scope and accept them as parameters for your functions or use some sort of state management.

```js
let user = ''

document.querySelector('#username').addEventListener('change',updateUser)

function updateUser(e) {
   user = e.target.value
}

document.querySelector('#dropdown').addEventListener('change',redirect)

function redirect(e) {
  const selection = e.target.value;
  
  if (selection === 'Z') {
    console.log(`mywebsite.com/${selection}${user}`)
    // window.location.replace(`mywebsite.com/${selection}${user}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`mywebsite.com/${selection}`)
    // window.location.replace(`mywebsite.com/${selection}`)
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="username" />

<select id="dropdown">
  <option>W</option>
  <option>X</option>
  <option>Y</option>
  <option>Z</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am self learning JavaScript and i started this week. So i won't lie to you and say that i still don't have the skills to fully comprehend your solution. It is getting late, so i will implement it tomorrow and give you feedback. However, i edited my current post with better clarifications.

Comment: @BigGwap no problem, man. Take a look at template literals to see if it helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Okay so your solution is almost it. I would like to know on "if (selection === 'Z')" can i simply replace 'Z' with my button's ID ? And if i remove the 'else' part entirely, would it affect the code ?

Comment: @BigGwap - I think you're on the right track. Remember that e.target.value means the event's (the click event) target's (the thing that got clicked ie. element with id dropdown) value (the value inside the option element). So you'll need to make sure that whatever you check in the if statement matches what is in the option value. The else statement is important because it allows all other links to just go to their target. If you'd like I can share an example that uses a more complex but more extendable solution.

Comment: yes i would like to see, so i can further my knowledge.